# How to resize svg in content attribute css?

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to resize an svg within a content attribute in css but without resizing the background.

How do I do that?

here is my current code

```
input[type='radio'] { 
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    transform: scale(3); 
}

input[type="radio"]:checked:before {
    content: url(./tickmark.svg);
    color: white;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #617D72;
}
```

svg code:

```
<svg width="14" height="10" viewBox="0 0 14 10" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M1 5L5 9L13 1" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Note that input elements should not have a before pseudo element (though some browsers may cope with it).

Comment: No [reprex]? We need to see the SVG code.

Comment: @RenevanderLende I added the svg code

Comment: You can try to use a different viewBox like `viewBox='-4 -6 22 22'` and no width and height for the svg element. Also take the advise of A Haworth

Answer (score 0):

```
svg{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

To my mind, Easiest way is resizing in CSS section